# How do I stop yfinance making 2 lines for each index date (2 timezones) in a dataframe with US and International stocks?

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I have a dataframe with a mix of US and UK stocks, yfinance has added a separate row for the UK stocks but I need the closing price for UK and US on the same row for that particular date. How can stop it making a new line for that date (presumably because of the TZ +5 hrs). Thank you.

Here's an example of the code:

```
import yfinance as yf
period = '1y'
tickers = ['SPY', 'QQQ', 'IUSA.L', 'VUKE.L']
df = yf.download(tickers, period=period,progress=False)['Close']
df.tail(10)
```

This is the result:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Add ignore_tz=True in the options so:

> ```
> df = yf.download(tickers, period=period,progress=False, ignore_tz=True)
> ```